# Take a screenshot of a external website in html2canvas javascript

Tags: javascript, url, screenshot, html2canvas

I am using javascript html2canvas for taking a screenshot of web page.
here is a code:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
 onrendered: function(canvas) {
 document.body.appendChild(canvas);
 }
});
```

how can I use url. Like if I want to take a screenshot of google.
Then what did I do for this..

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) will most likely prevent you from doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

If it was possible then you could, for example, have your website take a screen shot of a page on the user's company's intranet, or their online banking, or their web mail.

This would be a tremendous security hole and is therefore not allowed.

Comment: Then how didi they do. check this [ http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html ] link. Here they can take a screenshot of google.

Comment: They tell you at the top of the page — *proxy for loading the external pages/images into JSONP/CORS enabled page* — so it isn't really a third party external site (as far as the browser is concerned).

Comment: So, how can I take a sceernshot of external webpages. Anyother idea.?

Comment: You use a proxy so it isn't an external webpage.

Comment: @Quentin, this library can use or not a proxy. https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html check on their documentation. The person didn't ask to use a proxy to do it, he just want to have the screenshot doesn't matter how.

Comment: @Tito — From the page you linked to — "All the images that the script uses need to reside under the same origin for it to be able to read them without the assistance of a proxy."